# Why can't I run wbadmin from a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, wbadmin

I can run wbadmin from the command line like this:

```
$ c:\windows\system32\wbadmin.exe -?
```

And it works (I get a proper help message, ellided here).  However, when I try it in Ruby (as in this IRB session:)

```
irb(main):001:0> w=IO.popen('c:\windows\system32\wbadmin.exe -?')
```

I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - c:\windows\system32\wbadmin.exe -?
        from (irb):1:in `popen'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

This is preventing me from ever running wbadmin like this.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that your Ruby binary is 32-bit. A 32-bit program "sees" the "C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64" directory as "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32", and there's no `wbadmin.exe` in "C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64".

Comment: Thank you. This is good info.  I'll look into this and respond.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  This was exactly right.  I completely uninstalled Ruby 1.9 and installed Ruby 2.0-64 and everything works.  I would upvote you myself but I got no reputation.  :)

Comment: @ustamills - re: the upvote - That's alright-- I've got more than enough rep (though ewwhite is getting uncomfortably close). I'm glad I could help you out.